# sending discount is a line item for setexpresscheckout api

Tags: paypal

I am new to the paypal.how to use discount in the following code.

```
'&CURRENCYCODE='.urlencode($PayPalCurrencyCode).
                    '&PAYMENTACTION=Sale'.
                    '&ALLOWNOTE=1'.
                    '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE='.urlencode($PayPalCurrencyCode).
                    '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPPINGAMT='.urlencode($shipping_total).
                    '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT='.urlencode($cart_total).
                    '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT='.urlencode($item_total).
                    '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPPINGDISCAMT='.urlencode($discount_total).

                    $products_str.

                    '&AMT='.urlencode($item_total).
                    '&RETURNURL='.urlencode($PayPalReturnURL ).
                    '&CANCELURL='.urlencode($PayPalCancelURL);
```

how to write SetExpressCheckout_API  payment discount.

its work good without discount. so i don't khnow how to write discount here

please help me

Comment: sending discount is a line item for setexpresscheckout api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify discounts as line items by setting a negative amount in your L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0 parameter.
For example;

```
RETURNURL:  http://url
CANCELURL:  http://url
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT:   100.00
paymentrequest_0_currencycode:  USD
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT:   70.00
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPPINGAMT:   15.00
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_HANDLINGAMT:   10.00
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT:    5.00
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC:  Description
paymentrequest_0_paymentaction: Sale
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0:   Test article
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC0:   Description
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0:    70.00
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER0: 123456
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0:    1
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT0: 5.00
```

see [here](http://www.shopsandbox.de/api/ec/?call=SetExpressCheckout)